# Can you run Redis on Windows using Docker?

Tags: docker, redis

I know that Redis is not supported for Windows (at least newer versions).

My question is can I somehow use official builds of Redis on Windows using a Docker container? since Docker suppose to provide a compatible predictable environment for every platform

Comment: Just to be clear, Docker doesn't let you run Linux on Windows and vice versa. But WSL2 on Windows runs a Linux VM where you can run Linux programs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, you can run this

`docker run --name redis -d -p 6379:6379 redis:6.0`

Your applications will be able to access Redis on `localhost:6379`

Check this post, if you want a detailed explanation on installing a persisting redis deployment using Volume mounts. [link](https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/14993/how-to-quickly-deploy-redis-as-a-docker-container/)

For more info, check the official docs [link](https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/getting-started/getting-started-docker/)

Comment: Exactly what I needed! The -d flag detaches the console from the container. The -p flag binds a port from the container to the host. In this example, we're binding the host port 6379 to the container port 6379.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use redis via the WSL or use this [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jcreach/redis) built natively for docker Windows.
There is the latest version officially ported by Microsoft as well as the latest versions ported by the community.

Example of a docker command :

```
docker run --name my-redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis:5.0.14.1-lts-nanoserver-1809
```